# Change ImageView visibility from certain rows in RecyclerView

Tags: java, android

I am trying to change the visibility of an ImageView in a row that is selected. Essentially I want to behave when a user clicks on one row, an ImageView is shown in that row and hides the other ImageViews, and when the user clicks on a different row, it switches the ImageView viability to that row and hides the other ImageView in the previously clicked row.

Heres my code in my recyclerview adapter. I have it currently to show the ImageView on the row that is clicked BUT it currently does not hide the other ImageViews in the other rows!

```
public void onBindViewHolder(final PreGameSelectRecyclerAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (holder.isSelected.getVisibility() == View.INVISIBLE) {
                holder.isSelected.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            } else {
                holder.isSelected.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to add attribute in your recycled view data set that will keep track of vivble and invisble images.

I put this example for you which do what you want.

```
public class RecyclerViewActivity extends AppCompatActivity { 

private RecyclerView recycler;

@Override 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_recycler_view);
    initView(); 

    List<Item> items = Arrays.asList(
            new Item("1", false), 
            new Item("2", false), 
            new Item("3", false), 
            new Item("4", false), 
            new Item("5", false), 
            new Item("6", false), 
            new Item("7", false), 
            new Item("8", false), 
            new Item("9", false), 
            new Item("10", false), 
            new Item("11", false), 
            new Item("12", false), 
            new Item("13", false), 
            new Item("14", false), 
            new Item("15", false), 
            new Item("16", false), 
            new Item("17", false) 
    ); 

    recycler.setAdapter(new ContactsAdapter(items));
    recycler.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));

} 


class ContactsAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ContactsAdapter.ViewHolder> { 
    private List<Item> mItems;

    public ContactsAdapter(List<Item> items) {
        mItems = items;
    } 

    @Override 
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new ViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(
                parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row_recycler, parent, false));
    } 

    @Override 
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.bind(position);
    } 

    @Override 
    public int getItemCount() { 
        return mItems.size();
    } 

    class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder { 
        TextView mTextView;
        ImageView mImageView;

        ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            mTextView = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.textView);
            mImageView = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        } 

        void bind(int position) {
            final Item item = mItems.get(position);
            mTextView.setText(item.getText());

            itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override 
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    for (Item item1 : mItems) {
                        item1.setImageVisible(false);
                    } 
                    item.setImageVisible(true);

                    notifyDataSetChanged(); 
                } 
            }); 

            if (item.isImageVisible) mImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            else mImageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        } 
    } 
} 


class Item { 
    private String text;
    private boolean isImageVisible;

    public Item(String text, boolean isImageVisible) {
        this.setText(text);
        this.setImageVisible(isImageVisible);
    } 


    public String getText() {
        return text;
    } 

    public void setText(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    } 

    public boolean isImageVisible() { 
        return isImageVisible;
    } 

    public void setImageVisible(boolean imageVisible) {
        isImageVisible = imageVisible;
    } 
} 

private void initView() { 
    recycler = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.recycler);
} 


}
```